# Changed value doesn't detect by up and down arrow of type="number"

Tags: html, angular

I didn't do too much but up and down arrow doesn't detect the changes [when we type number manually it bind with totalQuantity but if we tries to use down or up arrow which is inside input box, it doesn't detect that value is changed. It shows me previous value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDjX6.png)

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" [(ngModel)]="totalQuantity" />
```

Comment: can you share your .ts code?

Comment: @chana, i didn't do too much in .ts. i just clicked up arrow and tries to save but it didn't give recent value. It gives me previous value

Comment: did you import FormsModule?

Comment: Yes, I imported it.

Comment: check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qcvo4n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check this in stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z1ntzg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: This is not waht I want. Arrows doesn't detect the changes. Whenever I click up arrow, value changed but it didn't bind in totalQuantity but works when we change value manaully.

Comment: capture the NgModelChange for input element.

Ref: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z1ntzg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Its handy. Thanx

Comment: Welcome @kabindhital